# Ruby (v 2.3.1) .each method on .split array not in any logical order

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, each

I have a simple string:

> "north west south east"

Which I want to **split** into sub-strings and put them as sub-arrays into one array, i.e:

```
[["direction", "north"], ["direction", "south"], ["direction", "east"], ["direction", "west"]]
```

However, the .each method seems neither to work through the elements alphabetically nor in the sequence they were entered.

The .each method seems to work through the split string in this order:

1. "north" (first sub-string) [second alphabetically]
2. "south" (thirdsub-string) [third alphabetically]
3. "west" (second sub-string) [last alphabetically]
4. "east" (last sub-string) [first alphabetically]

It definitely does not work through the sub-strings in alphabetical order, nor does it work through them in reverse order, but rather starts with the first sub-string and ends with the last, and **switches** the middle strings.

I just can't work it out.

Here is my code:

```
class Lexicon

  def scan(stuff)

    words = stuff.split

    #Empty arrays to easily push split words into
    @direction_array = []

    #Lexicons of different kinds of words
    @directions = ["north", "south", "east", "west", "down", "up", "left", "right", "back"]

    puts "This the original set"
    print words, "\n"

    while words.any? == true
      words.each do |word|
        if @directions.include? word
          puts "This is the word I selected: #{word}"
          @direction_array.push(['direction', word])
          words.delete word
          print @direction_array
          puts "This is what remains in the words set: #{words}"
        else
          "This word does not belong."
          words.delete word
          # puts "This is what remains in the words set: #{words}"
        end
      end
    end

    if @direction_array.any? == true
      puts "This is what we have in the direction array:"
      print @direction_array, "\n"
      return @direction_array
    else
      puts "Nothing to show for our efforts"
    end
  end
end

testing = Lexicon.new()
testing.scan("north south east west")
```

Comment: It's best to get out of the habit of adding needless code like `while x == true` or `if x == true` since `while x` is almost always going to do the job, especially in the case when `any?` will only return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 3):

If you delete an element from an array, then all the elements to the right of the hole left by the deleted element get shifted to the left to fill the gap.

You are deleting elements from your array *while* you are iterating over your array. If you only delete elements that you haven't iterated over yet, that will be okay. But if you delete an element that you have already iterated over, then all the elements to the right of the deleted element (including the one you *would have* iterated over next) get shifted left to fill up the hole left by the deleted element, which leads you to skip the next element.

You should *never ever* mutate a data structure while iterating over it, unless that is *explicitly* documented as a safe thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some ideas on how to make it more conventional in terms of Ruby:

```
class Lexicon
  # Declare things that are repeatedly used without being modified as
  # constants at the class-level.
  DIRECTIONS = %w[ north south east west down up left right back ]

  def scan(stuff)
    # Split the string and select all the words that are present
    # in the DIRECTIONS above.
    stuff.split.select do |word|
      DIRECTIONS.include?(word)
    end.map do |word|
      # Transform these into [ 'direction', x ] pairs
      [ 'direction', word ]
    end
  end
end
```

If you structure your code in neat, concise blocks like that, expressing your intent as a series of simple transformations, the code becomes quite easy to follow. Note there's no explicit `return` necessary here since that operation is returned by default, implicitly.

To exercise it you get this:

```
testing = Lexicon.new
testing.scan("north south east west")
# => [["direction", "north"], ["direction", "south"], ["direction", "east"], ["direction", "west"]]
```

The `p` method is really handy at showing the contents of variables, as is the `irb` tool for testing arbitrary code.

I think a number of problems in your original code came from doing the *iterate-and-delete* approach versus what should be a *filter* approach using `reject` or `select`. Deleting things from an array you're actively iterating over is often counter-productive, and as deleting things from arrays is actually quite computationally expensive, it's easier to construct a new array of only the elements you want.

Comment: This is a lot more elegant than my code, I will spend some time making sure I understand this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
dirs = "north west south east".split
  #=> ["north", "west", "south", "east"]

["direction"].product(dirs)
  #=> [["direction", "north"], ["direction", "west"],
  #    ["direction", "south"], ["direction", "east"]]
```

Comment: It doesn't get much easier. Note : you could define `dirs` with a split, and it would perfectly match the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could take this approach:

```
"north west south east".split.collect { |direction| ['direction', direction] }
```

Spliting your directions into elements of an **Array**, and then collecting them as you asked.